# Product repeating on Product index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run rails server locally, all 4 of my products are showing up correctly (see screenshot: [Products index on local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Top.png)), but when I open my site in Heroku, one product keeps repeating over and over in the 4 product spots. I tried to precompile my assets but that didn't seem to do anything.

I also have  config.serve_static_files = true and config.assets.compile = true 
in my production.rb file.

Here is my index.html.erb file and here is the site on Heroku: https://dedesign.herokuapp.com/products

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Products</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
        <% cache(cache_key_for_products) do %>
        <%= render partial: "product", locals: {product: product} %>
        <% end %>
      </div><!-- col div -->
    <% end %>
  </div><!-- row div -->
</div><!--container div -->  

<!-- remove table <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image url</th>
      <th>Colour</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
        <td><%= product.description %></td>
        <td><%= product.image_url %></td>
        <td><%= product.colour %></td>
        <td><%= product.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table> -->

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>`
```

Comment: Do you have the rails 12 factor gem installed?  What is @products?  Is it the same as Product.all in your heroku console?

Comment: Yes I have rails 12 factor gem installed. "Is it the same as Product.all in your heroku console?" --> How do I figure this out? Here is a link to my Products Controller code: https://github.com/dbukvic/nameofapp/blob/3345ab569c2b674ce649a9cb6c3f57c64fc21dc8/app/controllers/products_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that's a problem with your cache. A way to fix is

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
    <% cache(cache_key_for_products, product) do %>
      <%= render partial: "product", locals: {product: product} %>
    <% end %>
  </div><!-- col div -->
<% end %>
```

Here, I'm assuming that the `cache_key_for_products` is a method defined in your helper or something of sorts. I guess that should fix up the problem, but let me know if it doesn't.

**UPDATE**

I assumed the `cache_key_for_products` was returning a kind of AR::Collection/Record.

However, in your case, I think a better approach would be:

```
<% cache(@products) do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
      <% cache(product) do %>
        <%= render partial: "product", locals: {product: product} %>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- col div -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OR another approach would be:

```
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-4">
      <% cache [@products, product] do %>
        <%= render partial: "product", locals: {product: product} %>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- col div -->
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and am now getting a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" on my products index. Here is the cache_key_for_products code if that's helpful: 
'module ProductsHelper
 def cache_key_for_products
  count     = Product.count
  max_updated_at = Product.maximum(:updated_at).try(:utc).try(:to_s, :number)
  "products/all-#{count}-#{max_updated_at}"
 end
end'

Comment: Here is a link to it on github: https://github.com/dbukvic/nameofapp/blob/a00d846caf328e3efdf8dc2cfe044bc29291ae1b/app/helpers/products_helper.rb

Comment: Oh! I assumed that cache_key_for_products was a kind of AR instance/collection. Updating my answer now to reflect some changes. Basically, I guess the reason for defining the cache_key.. is to ensure that when the collection changes, the cache should be updated, however the `ActionView#cache` method would call the `cache_key` method on the passed in object/collection. In your case, I think what would work best is to cache the outermost layer(collection) and cache each object, otherwise, cache the collections with each object, which I assume you were trying to do before. Updating my answer now.

Comment: That worked! I tried the first approach and it's showing all the products now. Thanks so much, I appreciate it!